# qt creator opencv windows cmake error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake, qt-creator

I want to configure and then generate opencv library for qt creator to link them.
I opened cmake 3.1.0 and typed in the source and build path.

source:

```
C:/Users/Philipp_Laptop/Downloads/opencv/sources
build: C:/opencv-mingw
```

---

Then I configured the mingw-compiler with the path:

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/gcc.exe
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/g++.exe
```

---

After successful configure i set the with_Qt option.
I configured it twice and it shows me the following error:

---

```
Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:261 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "WIN32" will no longer be dereferenced when the
  policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be
  used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:127 (OCV_OPTION)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Test.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5TestConfig.cmake
    qt5test-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Test" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Test_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Test" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Concurrent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Concurrent", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Concurrent"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
    qt5concurrent-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Concurrent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Concurrent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Concurrent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


Looking for Q_WS_X11
Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
Looking for Q_WS_WIN
Looking for Q_WS_WIN - found
Looking for Q_WS_QWS
Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
Looking for Q_WS_MAC
Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
Found OpenGL: opengl32  
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_QTTEST_LIBRARY QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "4.8.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:374 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1331 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:34 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:447 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/opencv-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/opencv-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used *CMake GUI* under Windows for this so I'll refer to this approach.
Let's start from problems related to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH not defined`.
To solve this you simply have to press *ADD* on the *CMAKE GUI* and add the variable of type PATH named `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with value `C:/Bin/Qt/5.3/mingw482_32/lib/cmake/` but using your own installation of *Qt5*. The directory you point now contains all modules you need: Qt5 directory, Qt5AxBase...

At this point you press configure and you should have `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` not valid. You need to set it properly, in my case: `C:/Bin/Qt/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/qmake.exe`.

Then press configuration again and see if some error is still present (you have others error I never saw but maybe they are consequence of the previous ones), in my case this solved all issues and the build proceeded.

The *MINGW* configuration seems to be fine: I did slightly different just putting the bin MINGW path in PAT variable as first entry and using the default compiler from *CMAKE* (but your solution is as valid as my one).

Comment: How does Ubuntu find these modules? I've never had to specify `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` on Ubuntu.